# How to remove write-protected directories using the Terminal

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I am having trouble removing a file which cannot be removed manually via the File manager. Here is the code I tried putting into the Terminal:

```
rory@rory-laptop:~$ rm /var/www/html/index.html
rm: remove write-protected regular file '/var/www/html/index.html'? y
rm: cannot remove '/var/www/html/index.html': Permission denied
```

So as you can see, I am unable to remove the file. Does anyone have any ideas on what I should do to remove the file?

Comment: Use `sudo rm ...`?

Comment: Thank you. Sudo worked. I am going to delete this post now as it might be a duplicate.

Comment: Please don’t, duplicates serve as signposts!